# RangeValidator limiting that the ranges are 18 years after the date of birth

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, rangevalidator

This question may be difficult to convey. The goal is to make sure that the date inputted into the textbox is at least 18 years from the date of birth.

I have a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateFrom" runat="server"/>
```

I have a rangevalidator:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateFrom"    ErrorMessage="Age has to be more than 18 years" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

and I have an entity object:

```
rvtxtExecutiveDateTo.MinimumValue = (insiderObj.Insider.dateBirth ??     DateTime.MinValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I have set the range validator in the code behind to:

```
 RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = (insiderObj.Insider.dateBirth ??    DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(-18)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would *appear* to be with placement of the `AddYears` method call.

You have:

```
(insiderObj.Insider.dateBirth ?? DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(-18))
```

You probably meant:

```
(insiderObj.Insider.dateBirth ?? DateTime.MinValue).AddYears(-18)
```

Of course, this assumes that `dateBirth` is a *nullable* value  (`DateTime?`).  Otherwise, there'd be no reason to have `?? DateTime.MinValue` at all.

Also, you should not hardcode the `MM/dd/yyyy` format in the `ToString` call.  Per [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.minimumvalue.aspx):

> **Note**
>
> If you specify `ValidationDataType.Date` for the `BaseCompareValidator.Type` property without programmatically setting the culture for the application, you should use a culture-neutral format, such as **`YYYY/MM/DD`**, for the `MaximumValue` and `MinimumValue` properties. Otherwise, the date may not be interpreted correctly.

Either switch your format to `"yyyy/MM/dd"`, or configure your application to be culture-aware and either pass `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or omit the parameter entirely.